# Is it possible to use a newer MSVC++ compiler version (ie. from VS2015 or VS2013) in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to use VS2015 or at least latest VS2013 C++ compiler in VS2012 Ultimate, not installing ful VS2013/VS2015 IDE? Any form of standalone C++ compiler installer or source?